# Summary of all columns at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can i apply the following function on all columns of dataframe at once. I need to see the summary statistics of all columns.

```
summary(as.factor(as.character(dataframe$column1)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`summary` works with dataframes. For eg -

```
summary(mtcars)

    mpg             cyl             disp             hp             drat             wt       
 Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1   Min.   : 52.0   Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513  
 1st Qu.:15.43   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.8   1st Qu.: 96.5   1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581  
 Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :196.3   Median :123.0   Median :3.695   Median :3.325  
 Mean   :20.09   Mean   :6.188   Mean   :230.7   Mean   :146.7   Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217  
 3rd Qu.:22.80   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:326.0   3rd Qu.:180.0   3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610  
 Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :472.0   Max.   :335.0   Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424  
      qsec             vs               am              gear            carb      
 Min.   :14.50   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
 Median :17.71   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000   Median :4.000   Median :2.000  
 Mean   :17.85   Mean   :0.4375   Mean   :0.4062   Mean   :3.688   Mean   :2.812  
 3rd Qu.:18.90   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
 Max.   :22.90   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :8.000
```

For some reason if you have to change each column to first character and then  factor you may use `lapply` first and then use `summary`

```
dataframe[] <- lapply(dataframe, function(x) as.factor(as.character(x)))
summary(dataframe)
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked. Is there anyway to export them as csv neatly?

Comment: csv might not be the best choice for summary output. How about a text file? You may use `capture.output` for that. `capture.output(summary(dataframe), file = 'result.txt')`